# Opening hyperlink with target=_blank loads link in source page as well

Tags: html

I have a contact page which has links with target=_blank and they are all opening in new tabs, but also loading in the source page.

Code below - I am stumped, any advice would be appreciated.

```
<p style="font-size: 1.2em; color: #000; margin-top: 50px;">Contact</p><p class=""><a href="tel:+44 7942 062 664">+44 7942 062 664</a><br><a href="mailto:info@trentmcminn.com">info@trentmcminn.com</a></p><p class="">Follow Trent on <a href="http://twitter.com/Trent_McMinn" target="_blank" style="line-height: 2;">Twitter</a><br>Follow Trent on <a href="http://trentmcminn.tumblr.com" target="_blank" style="line-height: 2;">Tumblr</a></p><a target="_blank" href="http://eepurl.com/w3sb9" style="line-height: 2;">Subscribe to the newsletter</a>

        </div>
        <p style="font-size: 14px; position: absolute; bottom: 50px; padding-left: 40px;">All images © Trent McMinn 2013<br></p>
```

*EDIT* Page this is occurring is here http://www.trentmcminn.com/dev/contact/

THanks

Comment: I don't suppose there's any JS or anything that might be responsible...?

Comment: After placing your code into a jsFiddle, I do not see anything out of the ordinary. As Mark said, you might want to look into the scripts that you have written/are using

Comment: Thanks - ive just updated the original question with the page that this is occurring.

Comment: I see you have a jQuery PJAX script loaded. I suspect that is your trouble...

Comment: Disabling javascript made the issue go away, so it is definitely something to do with one of the scripts that is being loaded.

Comment: How is it the top menu, diary link opens in a new link if the issue is jquery/

Comment: Definately think that pjax is the culprit as I'm seeing some issues with what's showing up as line 335 for me "window.history.pushState(null, "", stripPjaxParam(options.requestUrl))
"

Comment: I'm thinking it's line 25 (onwards) in boulevard.js. It seems that all the links inside the `#lane` element (so not the main menu, to answer your earlier comment) trigger this peculiar behaviour. There's your problem I reckon.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this was correct, i removed the lane element and it worked perfectly.